# What is the equivalent statement in C language for .ORG?

Tags: c, embedded, processor, flash-memory

I am using Kinetis Design Studio IDE and the Processor on which am programming is MKE02Z64VLD2 (Kinetis E series). The Flash memory area of this processor is 0X0000_0000 to 0X07FF_FFFF . Am writing all codes in C language. I need to put a piece of code into the flash memory space of this processor. If its Assembly, then we use

.org 0X0000_0000 
{CODE}
where 0X0000_0000 is the starting address of the flash space.

What is its equivalent statement in C ?
( I know STACK OVERFLOW IS NOT A CODING SERVICE, am not asking the code, am asking for an equivalent C language statement of an assembly language statement )

Comment: stack overflow is not a coding or consulting service. Show your code and the **specific** problem you have.

Comment: I never asked you to give me the code. @Olaf . I would like you to look into the 2nd answer of this question already asked in this same site.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438492/how-to-write-function-at-particular-memory-location-in-flash-memory-is-there-an?answertab=oldest#tab-top). I am asking for a similar answer.

Comment: I think it is depended on the compiler, so you maybe need to read the compiler manual.  I'm using a renesas chip and its syntax is `#pragma section xxxxxx`.

Comment: Can you use inline assembly ?? I mean if your compiler supports inline assembly, then it would be hassle free

Comment: Although it is not exactly a howto code but you have put it in a poor way. It actually seems like you are asking for how to write the whole code while the truth is that you are actually asking for the equivalent code for `.org 0X0000_0000 {CODE}'` in C

Comment: @MayukhSarkar. Yes exactly u got my point.

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran Thanks...BTW..you can always use inline assembly if there in no portable API for a  particular assembly code

Comment: And I don't know whether it supports inline assembly, thanks for the lead. I'll find that soon.

Comment: I think your downvotes come from the way you have worded your question. You ask about the statement "in C language" and you have used the [tag:c] tag.  But people on this site interpret that as a question about the standard C language itself (as defined by the ISO standard); this is a generic language, portable to many machines, and it includes no machine-specific features like placing things at specific places in memory.  Individual compilers can do that, but it's not a feature of the language itself. So this isn't really a question about the C language, but about your compiler.

Comment: People seeing what appears to be a C question that really isn't may be getting annoyed and downvoting. So you may want to rephrase it (including the title) as a question about your particular compiler.

Comment: By the way, I have a feeling that even if you figure out how to do this, it won't achieve what you want.  Usually if you have to place code at a specific place in memory, it's because some hardware feature causes execution to start / transfer there under certain conditions.  But usually, it won't be under the same conditions under which a C compiler expects its code to run, so you can't put compiled C code there.  What most people would do is write a small piece of assembly code that gets the machine in a reasonable state and then jumps to the C code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in C. You have to do this via a custom linker script.

`linker.ld`:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

You can compile everything with (tune these to the environment you are targeting):

```
gcc -c file.c -o file.o
ld -T linker.ld file.o
```

`. = 0` tells the linker that everything will be loaded at address `0` and so all of your code should reference locations without an offset (or a custom one if you change it!) that is usually added in an operating system environment with virtual memory.

Do note this will not work if you are including libraries such as `stdio.h`, I think you will need to get a different linker script for this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. The usual use for .ORG 0 is to start definining manifest constants, for which the nearest equivalent is the `enum` statement. If you're defining code locations you're beneath the level of anything C will do for you.

Comment: what do you mean by " beneath the level of anything C will do for me" ?

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran it means that C is too high level, and what you're asking to do is too low level (as in assembly)